# How to run LOAD DATA INPATH hive command with wildcard from spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am creating a dataframe as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DataType, IntegerType, StringType
schma = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name",StringType(), True),
]
)
empdf=spark.read.format("csv").csv("/home/hdfs/sparkwork/hiveproj/Datasets/empinfo/emp.csv",schema=schma);
empdf.show();
```

I am saving the dataframe as a parquet file.

```
empdf.write.parquet(path="/home/hdfs/sparkwork/hiveproj/Data/empinfo/empl_par/")
```

**If I am using the specific file name in LOAD DATA INPATH command then it is working fine.**

```
spark.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/hdfs/sparkwork/hiveproj/Data/empinfo/empl_par/part-00000-6cdfcba5-49ab-499c-8d7f-831c9ec314de-c000.snappy.parquet' INTO TABLE EMPINFO.EMPLOYEE")
```

**But If i am using wildcard instead of file name(* or *.parquet) it is giving me error.**

```
spark.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/hdfs/sparkwork/hiveproj/Data/empinfo/empl_par/*.parquet' INTO TABLE EMPINFO.EMPLOYEE")
```

Is there a way to push all the contents of a folder using wildcard in hive command from spark?
please help with the same.

Comment: for better performance try using spark functions instead of hive - ```spark.read.format("parquet").load("/home/hdfs/sparkwork/hiveproj/Data/empinfo/empl_par/*.parquet").write.insertInto("EMPINFO.EMPLOYEE")```

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me. Thank you Srinivas.

Comment: Just a follow up question on this. I think i can avoid parquet file creation in my job. isn't it? 
Once i read the csv file, I get empdf dataframe. I can directly write this data frame to hive table isn't it?
spark.write.insertInto("EMPINFO.EMPLOYEE") 
Since the table data is configured to store as parquet , the data will be stored as parquet if we use insertInto(). Am i right?

Comment: yes, you just have to call df.write.insertInto(..)

Comment: if the target table is partitioned, then do we need to mention the partition column along with insertInto()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `spark.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/hdfs/sparkwork/hiveproj/Data/empinfo/empl_par/*.parquet' INTO TABLE EMPINFO.EMPLOYEE")`

try using this `empdf.write.partitionBy("year","month","day").insertInto("EMPINFO.EMPLOYEE")`

**Note** I have used partition columns as `year`,`month` & `day`. You may need to change as per your requirement.